# How to change location of the Blockchain with monero GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

How can I set the daemon included with the GUI to sync the blockchain from a directory on a flash drive, rather than the default directory ?

Answer (score 23):

The GUI has two ways to do that:

When starting the Daemon:

[image]

Or in the settings Page:

[image]

As a note: on Linux and OS-X it's: `--data-dir /path/to/your/blockchain`

Comment: To elaborate, you can change the file path to your desired directory. For instance, you can change it to --data-dir=C:\Monero or wherever you want to put it. Just change the part after --data-dir=

Comment: medusa answered perfectly, however missed an important detail that the directory cannot contain spaces or it will not work.

Comment: Is there a way around this spaces limitation, such as using backslashes or something? I want to move to a networked drive that is not easy to change the name to remove spaces